# How to list sample of files from a directory

Tags: linux, files

I have a directory that contains hundred thousands of files.
I need to list sample of these files (example 10 files), without processing all the files found in the directory which will take too much processing time.

Comment: It appears the answer you want is [described over here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/414164/114147), assuming you use bash or similar variants.

Comment: @invert actually, sorting a list of hundred thousands of files is probably not such a good idea. Maybe use `ls -f| tail -n 1000` instead of just `ls` for the answer in the link

Comment: `tail` is aweful in this case, since it will wait for `ls` to finish its work! `head` would terminate it after reading the 1000 lines it needs.

Comment: However you throw it, you're going to have to interrogate the inode structure. You could use a file indexer to query instead, note that will require an initial directory scan too. see [man locate](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate+1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can sample from the whole file list without reading them all in some way or the other, even on the filesystem level.

*Unless* their names follow a pattern that is (eg. fileXXXXXXX), in which case you could pregenerate a random list of names before accessing the files. For such a large amount of files it would be odd if their names were random.

But let's assume you're not that lucky. Using `find` is prefered over `ls`, since it can escape output with null, making it immune to nonstandard characters in filenames. If we don't want to read all the files, it is the fastest to use the ones at the start of the listing. To get a better sample, I would use a bigger sample first (`$oversamplesize` below) and then do a random subselection of size `$samplesize` from there. I didn't manage to make `sort -R` or `shuf` work well with null separators, so the shuffling and final selection is done by `awk`:

```
 find ~ -type f -print0 | 
 grep --null --null-data -m ${oversamplesize:-100} . | 
 awk -v samplesize=${oversamplesize:-11} -vRS='\0' -vORS='\0' \
   '{ a[NR]=$0 } END {srand(); while (i<samplesize) { b=(int(rand()*10000)%samplesize); if (b in c) {continue;} else {c[b]=a[b]; print a[b]; i++;} }; }' | 
 xargs -0 echo # echo here being just a dummy
```

Two notes here. For some reason, it often also prints an empty filename, so I increased the sample size just in case. The trivial note is not to forget to change the search path (~ here) and the final command.